# Dynamically created css not working on Azure website

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-web-app-service, production-environment

I am working on Web Form project to deploy on production. In this project, dynamic folder is created on fly and put the new *css* style as per data configuration from database. This was handled by **Handlers** in web form. Application works locally without any error. But when I publish on production it does not find the dynamic created css file path. Its not physical exists it creates on fly. So it fails to download css and it missing all images and styles. Another team had developed this application and we are moving this from FireHost to Azure site. It was working on Firehost but no any luck on Azure site yet. I tried to remove manifest file in production by adding remove attributes .manifest in web.config. But no any luck yet. I appreciate your help Thanks

I am getting 404 errors, 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I have the style css inject this way in site.master page.

```
 <link href="/Styles/Dynamic/CompanySite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It did not mentioned handlers in web.config. There is separate handlers folders and pages. In pages code behind file look like this in page load method.

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Styles/CompanyStyles.css")));

        string sPrimaryColor = "#B1D74C";
        string sSecondaryColor = "#8BBB29";
        string sPrimaryTextColor = "#000";
        string sSecondaryTextColor = "#000";
        string sBannerId = "1";

        try
        {
            var settings = new CompanySettingDataLogic().Retrieve();
            if (settings != null)
            {
                sPrimaryColor = settings.primary_color_txt;
                sSecondaryColor = settings.secondary_color_txt;
                sPrimaryTextColor = settings.primary_text_color_txt;
                sSecondaryTextColor = settings.secondary_text_color_txt;
            }

            var BannerId = new CompanyThemeDataLogic().GetBannerId();
            if (BannerId.HasValue)
                sBannerId = BannerId.Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            new Data.Config.ErrorLogDataLogic().LogException(Ex);
        }

        sb.Replace("#PRIMARY#", sPrimaryColor);
        sb.Replace("#SECONDARY#", sSecondaryColor);
        sb.Replace("#PRIMARYTEXTCOLOR#", sPrimaryTextColor);
        sb.Replace("#SECONDARYTEXTCOLOR#", sSecondaryTextColor);
        sb.Replace("#BANNERIMAGEID#", sBannerId);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: You should share how the handlers section in your web.config look like, what error you're getting back (404?), have you tried to enable `Failed Request Tracing` and see what is exactly failing?

Answer (score 0):

> Its not physical exists it creates on fly. So it fails to download css
>   and it missing all images and styles.

Where have you stored the files after the folder being created? Do you store them in website Azure vm disk? Please note

1. the VM disk storage is not persistent
2. if you have >= 2 instances on Azure to host the web app, and then you just created the css/images files on 1 instance (VM), later your end user may hit the other instance that has no such files.

so please store your files in [`Azure storage - blob`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) and use its url in your project to connect to css/image files

Comment: It does not stored on VM.  Images and styles stored in database and then it writes images dynamically in newly created Dynamic folders. There is structure Styles/Dynamic/CompanySite.css and in this css styles few images are rendered from Images/Dynamic/.png location.  There is no physical Images/Dynamic and Styles/Dynamic folder in projects.